# How do I make sure that each instance of my angular model has certain characteristics?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-model

I have some tasks to do . I want to make sure that each task has a maximumFundPossible property of $1000 constant, a currentfund property that is variable as it will be updated as tasks are being funded , a budget property that is variable but constant for each task item . That task item property has to be set to a certain amount when being created. I guess I will have to add an input field for that amount to be set during task creation ? How ?

I already have my todo tasks but I am stuck as I am a few days new to angular and I hope to fully learn it through this project.

How do I modify my code so that my todo tasks have the described above properties? Also, when I click do button or do for free button, etc, will my current views keep track of that specific task X ? How do I keep track of that task X so that my do , doforfree or any other function I will be using affects only that specific task X.

I know it s too much to ask but angularjs just has a high learning curve.
Thanks a lot for your help

Here is my todoController:

```
facebookExample.controller('todoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
// Initialize the todo list array
//if local storage is null save the todolist to local storage
$scope.todoList = [];

if (localStorage.getItem("mytodos") === null)
{

 localStorage.setItem("mytodos", angular.toJson($scope.todoList));

 }else
 {
 //set the todolist from local storage
 $scope.todoList = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem("mytodos"));
 }


 // Add an item function
 $scope.todoAdd = function() {
 //check to see if text has been entered, if not exit
 if ($scope.todoInput === null || $scope.todoInput === ''){return;}

 //if there is text add it to the array
 $scope.todoList.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput, done:false});

 //clear the textbox
 $scope.todoInput = "";

 //resave the list to localstorage
 localStorage.setItem("mytodos", angular.toJson($scope.todoList));
 };



 // Each task is limited to limit total funding = $1000
 //current funding ; max funding; ballance funding = $1000-current
 // Variables or columns for taskX  





/****************/
// Task Counter for Task X
// If task-assignment is aproved by admin
// Set Task Counter to D-63
// Send reminder to Person assigned for task X in Due Date
// Do for money button is diabled unless task is funded
// Do for free is always enabled unless task is already assigned 








 /**************/
 //Updating state of task to done only on due date
 // if Dtime > DueDate
     // UserX can update task to done

     // Admin is notified by email of the action

     // Admin should aprove of disaprove within 3 days

     // Admin can aprove to Done or  Undone









 /*******************/
 // Admin aproves of Task X to done
 // Task X is updated to state of done


 //if for moeny and amount raised for task >

 // Payment is initiated to Tasker if task was funded and done for money
 // Payment initiated from Company to Admin if task was done for free






  //Do button
  $scope.do = function(){
  // If current user clicks do, 
  // Assign the current user to the task with a state of pending admin aproval

  // Counter variable for dute date is initiated with D-63
  };



 $scope.doForFree = function(){

 // Task is assigned to user with a state of pending-aproval-of-admin-     assignment-do-for-free
 // Admin is notified of do-for-free-request

 };



 // if admin aproves user that requested to do task X for money
   // task X is assigned to that user
   // state of task is assigned to admin-aproved-assignment-for-money
   // the User is notified of admin aproval
   // Task due date is created/updated




// if admin aproves user that requested to do task X for free
  // task X is assigned to that user
  // state of task is assigned to admin-aproved-assignment-for-free
  // the User is notified of admin aproval
  // Task due date is created/updated




 //fund button

 $scope.fund = function(){

 //Redirect current user to paypal for payment to You-Serve


 // Maximum payment cannot exceed Maximum amount - what 's already funded
   // Need to keep track of already funded amount 
   //  Need to keep track of task cost/price







 // If paypal payment was done successfully
    // Update already funded amount 
    // Update maximum amount for extra funding
    // update the fully funded variable/boolean
    // Send task/user/amount to database



 // If payment fails, take out state of being funded
 };





  $scope.remove = function() {
  //copy list
  var oldList = $scope.todoList;
  //clear list
  $scope.todoList = [];
  //cycle through list
  angular.forEach(oldList, function(x) {
  //add any non-done items to todo list
    if (!x.done) $scope.todoList.push(x);
 });
 //update local storage
 localStorage.setItem("mytodos", angular.toJson($scope.todoList));

};

//The Update function
//This waits 100ms to store the data in local storage
$scope.update = function() {
//update local storage 100 ms after the checkbox is clicked to allow it to     process
setTimeout(function(){
 localStorage.setItem("mytodos", angular.toJson($scope.todoList));
 },100);


};

}]);
```

And here is my view:

```
<div ng-app="facebookExample" view-title="Tasks">
<div ng-controller="todoController">
<h1>Tasks</h1>

 <div class="item item-input-inset">
 <label class="item-input-wrapper">
 <!-- The actual input tag which is bound to the todoInput using ng-model -->
 <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Item" ng-model="todoInput" size="100"> 
 </label>
 <!-- Our button thay will call our funtion to add a new todo item -->
<button class="button button-small" ng-click="todoAdd()">
Add Task
</button>
</div>

  <div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
  <li class="item item-checkbox">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="checkbox">
  </label>
  <!-- this is the checkbox element, you will see it is bound to the done setting in the items array -->
  <!-- When clicked it calls the update function to update the item to its done status -->
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done" ng-click="update()"/>
  <!-- this is a span tag that shows the item text, I am using ng-bind, instead of the span tag we could have used {{x.todoText}} as well -->
  <button class="fund-button" style= "float: left;" ng-click="fund()">Fund</button>
  <span>{{x.todoText}}</span>
  <button class="doButton" style= "float: right; margin-right: 2px;" ng-click="do()">Do</button>
  </li>
  </div>
  <!-- the remove button will call the remove function and remoave all items that   are marked done -->
  <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="remove()">Remove Checked Tasks
  </button>
  </div>
   </div>:
```

Comment: you really need to simplify the question because it is getting muddled with the business rules. firstly, you can pass the value "item" to your actions such as do(item) and fund(item) and remove(item). Just change your function such that it takes an argument of item.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple of example of passing an item from ng-repeat to your actions:

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newMessage">
    <button ng-click="addMessage(newMessage)">
    Add
    </button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
        {{message}}
        <button ng-click="remove(message, $index)">remove</button>
        <button ng-click="uppercase(message, $index)">uppercase</button>
        <button ng-click="lowercase(message, $index)">lowercase</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.newMessage = '';
  $scope.messages = [];
  $scope.addMessage = function(msg) {
    $scope.messages.push(msg);
  };
  $scope.remove = function(msg, index) {
    $scope.messages.splice(index, 1);
  };
  $scope.uppercase = function(msg, index) {
    $scope.messages[index] = msg.toUpperCase();
  };
  $scope.lowercase = function(msg, index) {
    $scope.messages[index] = msg.toLowerCase();
  };
}
```

take a look at the jsfiddle and really understand how data is being referenced by your actions. for example, I am using the implicit $index variable to access the array of messages.

http://jsfiddle.net/heavyhorse/x4b2w84c/

Comment: any idea how i would do that in my specific case ?